# uploading large file in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload

I need to make a module for uploading files with type *.flv in PHP.

I have been successful in uploading small files but am unable to upload large files.

I have updated PHP values like

```
php_value memory_limit 120M
php_value max_execution_time 120
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
php_value max_input_time 500
```

I am doing a file upload using PHP, which works fine for a file of size 2.8MB on my localhost - but not my Mediatemple GS host. Files smaller than 2MB work fine, but anything larger seems to not work. I am not getting any error message but when the upload finishes, the file is not found in the uploads directory.

I searched around, and added the following lines to the .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 120M
php_value max_execution_time 120
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
php_value max_input_time 500
```

but it is still not working. Please help.

Comment: if you are using shared hosting ... then is not possible `unless` you are willing to spent more $$$

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors? Or is the script timing out?

Comment: Ask your hosting provider, are you allowed to change those values in the first place? Because you might think they have been changed, but other restrictions have been imposed elsewhere.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` to see what the values are **really** set to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your max_execution_time is more 2 minutes !
check how time your script run.
Usually for upload big file developper use FTP or host sharing. (megaupload/rapidshare/...)

Answer (score 0):

i guess all you need is

```
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");    # 2 GB
set_time_limit(0);          # unlimited exec time
```

i read somewhere in PHPdocs that it only allows upto 2GB file transfer